# Retrieve Json parse object

Tags: json, object, parsing

I’m trying to retrieve certain data from an object. From what I am told this is called a JSON parse (this is new to me but that’s what I’m told it’s called).

I’ve searched stack + multiple sites and I cant find what I need.

Here’s my code, I want to console log the **source** only.

```
{"results":[{"bounce_rate":100,"source":"Direct / None","visitors":4},{"bounce_rate":0,"source":"domain.co.uk","visitors":1}]}
```

Here’s how I am getting the data so far.

```
let req = new Request(fullurlfiltered)

req.method = "GET"

req.headers={
  "Authorization":api,
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
}

response = await req.loadString()


response = await req.loadString()
const source = response;
console.log(response)
```

I’ve tried

```
const source = response[0];
Const source = response.results.source
```

Nothing works and I’m lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you wasn't far off.

```
let req = new Request(fullurlfiltered)

req.method = "GET"

req.headers={
  "Authorization":api,
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
}

response = await req.loadString()


response = await req.loadString()
const result = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(result.results[0].source)
console.log(result.results[1].source)
```